# Using Chrome Tools to inject CSV information into sporcle quiz

Tags: import, javascript, csv

I've just started a project where I plan to scrape information from wikipedia articles and put it into a quiz on Sporcle. I've scraped my information and have it in CSV format, but I'm struggling to find a way to automatically inject that into the interactive quiz generator. I could enter the text manually, but I plan on doing many of these quizzes and it will be too time consuming and error prone to do it that way.

Here is a snippet of my CSV:

```
Jamie Lawson,Jamie Lawson,1
George Ezra,Wanted on Voyage,2
Mark Ronson,Uptown Special,1
Years & Years,Communion,2
Blur,The Magic Whip,1
```

Here is a screenshot of Sporcle:
[image]

In an ideal world, Sporcle would be able to take information from an uploaded CSV, but that option is not available. Next most ideal would be if pasting my CSV into the table in the browser populated all of the cells, however, it pastes the entire contents into one cell.

So my questions is can I make my life easier somehow using the developer tools in chrome? Is there a quick way to inject that CSV information into the page? Note that the columns in my CSV differ to the screenshot, but I can easily reorder my CSV if needed.

In order to help me out, you'll probably need to have a sporcle account and to go to the interactive quiz creator, so this is probably a long shot!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with some Java code.
Basically parse the file to read in the table, then have it manually enter each one, using the robot.